# How do I allow for an input to find what's in a list with the same name? (Python)

Tags: python, list, input

I'm trying to work a bit of code that gets you to input the name of a list in order to check what's in said list - but I'm not sure how to make it work.

I'm not using the full thing because there's over 1000 bits to the database, but here's a simpler version.

```
thingone= [yellow, sweet]
thingtwo = [red, sour]
number = input("What is it you would like?")
```

*User here inputs "thingtwo".*

```
print(number[0] + " is the colour, " + number[1] + " is the taste.")
```

How would I get it to output "red is the colour, sour is the taste."?
Right now, all I'm getting is a "str is not callable" error.

Comment: Then you should not use named variables but a dictionary and match the keys